# How do you set background style for selected list items?

Tags: android

I am having problems defining a ListView with a custom adapter and list item xml layout. The problem is that my ListView is not highlight items when pressed. I am doing the following:

I define a drawable selector xml resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

I define an item layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_voice_item" 
     >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/voiceItemFavorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_favorite" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/voiceItemText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/voiceItemFavorite"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_voice_item" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally I wrote code in my custom data adapter to inflate and populate then view.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.voice_item, null);
    }
    VoiceItem i = getItem(position);
    TextView t = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.voiceItemText);
    t.setText(i.toString());
    ImageButton b = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.voiceItemFavorite);
    b.setTag(i);
    b.setSelected(i.favorite);
    b.setOnClickListener(new FavoriteClick());
    return convertView;
}
```

Everything works except when I press items in the list there is no visual indication of the press. I expect the color of the pressed item's background to transition to the style defined by my drawable selector.

How can I both have a custom view items and retain styling highlighting of items while pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `android:background="@drawable/btn_voice_item"` is solid image so it'll cover the `ListView` selector. Here is very detail tutorial about custom `ListView selector` and item backround 
[ListViewTipsandTricks part3](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=454) (Cyril Mottier)

Comment: Thanks Cyril. I actually read your blog post before you replied and your demo help me fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

this is the xml i use. note that this is gradient. but put this in your @android:color/holo_orange_light

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
  android:startColor="#18d7e5"
  android:centerColor="#16cedb"
  android:endColor="#09adb9"
  android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

this is my selector:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
 </selector>
```

and this is what i have in the list xml file:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >
```

perhaps you find this useful and can work out your problem

Comment: sorry, that's not doing it for me. can you send me an example project? that would be much appreciated.